# Standard parameter representation in neural networks

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Many times I have seen in neural networks forward propagation that example vectors are multiplied from the left (vector-matrix) and some times from the right (matrix-vector). Notation, some Tensorflow tutorials and the datasets I have found seem to prefer the former over the later, contrary to the way in which linear algebra tends to be teached (matrix-vector way).

Moreover, they represent inverted ways of representing parameters: enumerate problem variables in dimension 0 or enumerate neurons in dimension 0.

This confuses me and makes me wonder if there is really a standard here or it has been only coincidence. If there is, I would like to know if the standard follows some deeper reasons.  I would feel really better answering this question.

(By the way, I know that you will normally use example matrices instead of vectors [or more complex things in conv nets, etc..] because the use of minibatches, but the point still holds.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer is what you are looking for, but in the context of Tensorflow, the standard is to use a dense layer (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) which is a higher level abstraction that wraps up the affine transformation logic you are referring to.

Comment: If that is right, tensorflow effectively use the example-parameters ("vector-matrix") multiplication order as standard, because dense layers use the [batch_size, variable_size]  format for example matrices.

Comment: It is right in the sense that this is what the industry standard is as far as using Tf goes.